# making a diamond of 0 in a 1's matrix - numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

so the assignment is:
write a func that gets N ( int greater than 0 ) and return a 2d array of 1's  where a path of 0 makes a diamond. the length of each diamond line(1 of 4 lines) is of length N. cannot use loops list comps or recursion.

i will add my own solution but I don't think it is very numpy oriented..
please note that my solution was originally for a diamond of 1's in a 0 matrix so it might look a bit odd

example:
n=1

```
np.array([[0]])
```

n=2:

```
np.array([[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]])
```

n=3

```
np.array([[1,1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,1,1]])
```

My Solution:

```
    if n == 1:
        finalMatrix = np.array([[0]])
        return finalMatrix
    rawMatrix = np.ones((2 * n - 1, 2 * n - 1))
    midRowDiag = np.eye(2 * n - 1, k=n - 1)
    midColDiag = np.eye(2 * n - 1, k=-(n - 1))
    tempMatrix = rawMatrix - midRowDiag - midColDiag
    halfMatrix = tempMatrix[::, n:]
    # print(halfMatrix)

    # Making the quarters
    topRightQuart = halfMatrix[:n - 1, 0:n - 1]
    topLeftQuart = np.fliplr(topRightQuart)
    botLeftQuart = np.flipud(topLeftQuart)
    botRightQuart = np.flipud(topRightQuart)
    midCol = tempMatrix[:, n - 1]
    midRow = tempMatrix[n - 1, :]
    # Adding them all up
    finalMatrix = np.zeros((2 * n - 1, 2 * n - 1))
    finalMatrix[:, n - 1] += midCol
    finalMatrix[n - 1, :] += midRow
    finalMatrix[0:n - 1, 0:n - 1] += topLeftQuart
    finalMatrix[0:n - 1, n:] += topRightQuart
    finalMatrix[n:, 0:n - 1] += botLeftQuart
    finalMatrix[n:, n:] += botRightQuart
    finalMatrix[n - 1, n - 1] = 1
    return finalMatrix
```

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: @azro i would like to see a more numpy oriented solution

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = np.diagflat([1,1],1)
arr = np.maximum(arr,np.flip(arr,0))
arr = np.maximum(arr,np.flip(arr,1))  
arr = np.where((arr==0)|(arr==1), arr^1, arr)
```

As per my understanding you are looking to make diamonds write. This is an example for 3x3 one for 5x5 the code is underneath

```
arr = np.diagflat([1,1,1],2)
arr = np.maximum(arr,np.flip(arr,0))
arr = np.maximum(arr,np.flip(arr,1))  
arr = np.where((arr==0)|(arr==1), arr^1, arr)
```

so for n needs to be a odd number and n=odd number
`list of 1 len = n//2+1` and the second parameter in  `np.diagflat` will be `n//2`. This is important to use // or you can simply divide and round it off

if **n** is the length of diagonal then the second parameter will be **n-1**

Comment: no, n can be any number.. as n is the length of every diamond line, not the shape of the matrix

Comment: No issue then len of diamond line is n then then the parameter will be n-1. If you want the full code I can write it for you.

Comment: please check it and let me know if anything else is needed here

Comment: can you please explain the code in words?

Comment: diag flat filles populates the field in right side of the intended matrix, then to get the whole thing just need to take the mirror around origin of matrix once left side and the pulling the whole thing down. but flip does it by just flipping it so here you need to use maximum to retain the changes

Comment: thank you! genius solution!! @Arunbh Yashaswi

Answer (score 0):

This pattern looks similar to a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix). You can implement this using [`scipy.linalg.toeplitz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html):

```
>>> p = np.array([1,1,0,1,1])
>>> T = toeplitz(p, p)
```

Notice the layout of `T`:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

We can horizontally flip it ([`np.fliplr`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html)) and point-wise multiply with itself:

```
 >>> T*np.fliplr(T)
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

---

Minimal implementation:

```
def diamond(n):
    pad = (1,)*(n-1)
    p = np.array(pad + (0,) + pad)
    T = toeplitz(p, p)
    return np.fliplr(T)*T
```

Then:

```
>>> diamond(1)
array([[0]])

>>> diamond(2)
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])

>>> diamond(3)
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
```